# PHP 1x while 2x for loop slows the loading extremely

Tags: php, mysql

on a start i want to say that i'm absolutely new in PHP and MySQL.

After making few loops **1 x While loop** (for getting data from DB ) and **2x for loop** for making dynamic links based on "level" in DB loading of that specific page started to be slow. I'am using MAMP on localhost.

Tried to find some fixes ( first thought that the MAMP is problem ), but now i dont know if that 2x for loop isn't too much heavy for the page. When i delete both FOR LOOPS problems dissapears.

Can be that because of the MAMP (it will run ok online) or it is realy heavy and someone see anything that slows the page?

**Thanks for help**

```
<?php
session_start();
require('connect.php');
$level1 = "<p class='text-center mt-5' style='font-size:8vh'>Bez přihlášení do této sekce nemáte přístup</p>";  

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $logmsg = "<p class='logged-in'>Jste přihlášen jako <b>$username</b>. <a href='process/logout.php'>Odhlásit se</a></p>";
    $level1 = "<p class='level'><a href='levels/level1.php'>Level1</a></p>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='$username'";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $_SESSION['level'] = $row["level"];
        }
    }

    for ($i = 0 ; $i <= $_SESSION['level'] ; $i++) { 
        ${"level$i"} = "<p class='level-size'><a href='levels/level$i.php'>Hádanka $i</a></p>";

    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Úvod</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand+SC&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">


    <style type="text/css">
        label,small,button div {
            font-size: 2.5vh
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body class="second-page-body">
    <?php if(isset($logmsg)){ ?><div class="text-right"> <?php echo $logmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center p-5"><strong>Willkommen</strong></h1>
    <div class="level-container">   
        <?php for ($i=0; $io <= $_SESSION['level'] ; $i++) { 
                if(isset(${"level$i"})){
                    echo ${"level$i"};
            }
        } ?>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**EDIT**
Tested few sites and it looks that problem sometimes occurs on other sites too. ( maybe combination of MAMP localhost error + for loops are extremely slow )

Comment: Your second for-loop is comparing the variable `$io` instead of `$i`; is that supposed to be the case? If it's not defined, then you're effectively running an infinite loop in your second for-loop (since it'll never terminate)

Comment: Why are you transferring lots of data from the database to the session? You're not going to get any performance benefit. OTOH if you can assume the data will be consistent in the session, it will also be consistent in the client cache (where there is a potential performance gain.

Comment: Your code is quite a mess. You should read something about templating systems and database abstraction *(or use at least `PDO`)*. I don't know how (if) you sanitize the `username` when your users enter it, but there's a glaring [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) attack vector. *(see https://xkcd.com/327/)*

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 
    for ($i=0; $io <= $_SESSION['level'] ; $i++) { 
            if(isset(${"level$i"})){
                echo ${"level$i"};
        }
    } ?>
```

There seems to be an error with **$io <= $_SESSION['level']**. I think it should be 
**$i <= $_SESSION['level']**

**EDIT**
Thanks for help. Also find the IF statement to be useless there.

I think there's a wrong use or manipulation of loops and control statements. Try to optimize your code, it should make loading faster